# HTTP or HTTPS on virtual private cloud (VPC)?

Tags: http, https, cloud, google-compute-engine, vpc

Should I use `HTTP` or `HTTPS` to communicate between services on my virtual private network (VPC)? What are the risks (if any) of using `HTTP` in such scenario?

My naive reasoning is that given the inherent privacy of the network, `HTTP` should be suffice for internal communication between servers inside of said network. Am I wrong to make such assumption?

I've searched through [GCloud VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/overview) documentation, yet can't find anything regarding this question. I've also found this [article on AWS HTTPS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ssl-offload-enable-traffic-and-verify-certificate.html), yet again no indication as to whether one or other should be preferred.

I'd link up more sources, but I can not find any articles arguing for either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, a VPC network isolates the traffic and puts some security measures in place that prevent your traffic from being seen from a different VPC. That being said, the security of the resources is a shared responsibility in cloud environments. In case there is a security breach inside GCP that allows someone to gain access to my VPC and sniff the traffic, if I'm using HTTPS, the communication is encrypted and I am adding another layer of security. Therefore, I would always go with the safest option (HTTPS).